# php session management with redis - TTL expirations don't get updated on reads

Tags: php, session, redis, ttl

I'm using redis as backend for php session management on a multiserver configuration.

Redis is using `session.gc_maxlifetime` for setting TTL, but TTL does not update on session reads. It only updates on writes.

It means that I must add a change on a session value `$_SESSION ['dummy'] = time();` on each request to keep the session alive.

Is this the expected behavior?
should I change to memcached or write custom php session module?

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not automatically reset the TTL for you when you read a key. If you want to refresh a session's TTL when you read it, you need to do so in the application via a pipeline.

Comment: question was in the php session manager context. It should update TTL after every request.